# Entity Framework Core Code First Model Navidation Properties

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a Web API that uses entity framework.  I have several tables there were created using the code first setup.  My Competitions class is defined below.

Everything works great and I'm able to get my `Competitions` table data along with all the data in the navigation properties that are returning a collection.  However, I'm not able to get any values for the `CompetitionTypes` and `Users` navigation properties.  `OwnerId` references `UserId` in the `Users` table.

How would I get the linked data in my `CompetitionTypes` and `Users` table?  I basically want the same thing as the three collection navigation properties, except that `CompetitionTypes` and `Users` would only return one row.

```
    public partial class Competitions
    {
        [Key, Required]
        public int CompetitionId { get; set; }
        public int CompetitionTypeId { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string CompetitionName { get; set; }

        public CompetitionTypes CompetitionTypeId { get; set; }
        public Users UserId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Participants> Participants { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ResultStats> ResultStats { get; set; } 
        public ICollection<Results> Results { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have referenced the `OwnerId` to the `CompetitionTypes` and `Users` table instead of the `CompetitionId` that is the PK for the `Competitions` table you want to reference? Your tables are not empty? Do you tried `.Include()` method at loading data - lazy loading will be supported since EF Core 2.1? How do you query the database - could you provide the code that should work? Which EF Core version do you use?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I figured out my problem, or at least a work around.  As you pointed out I was not calling .Include on `CompetitionTypes` so I fixed that.  As for `Users`, I had to change my table column name from `OwnerId` to `UserId` and that did the trick. I'm guessing EF was having trouble linking because it must have been looking for a `UserId` field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

EF auto-matches FK properties with navigation properties based on conventions. Namely, it expects FK properties to be named the same as navigation properties, just with `Id` at the end. In other words, for it to automatically match up `OwnerId`, you'd need a navigation property like:

```
public User Owner { get; set; }
```

Since your navigation property is `UserId`, it's actually looking for a property named `UserIdId`.

If you don't want to follow conventions, then you must either use the `ForeignKey` attribute or fluent config to tell EF which property belongs with which.

That said, there's some pretty major issues with your naming of things here. First, entities should always be singular `User`, not `Users`. Second, you should not have navigation properties that end with `Id`: e.g., `User`, not `UserId`. Only actual PK or FK properties should end with with `Id`. Finally, don't prefix properties on your entity with the entity name. This last one is mostly for readability. Which is more natural: `competition.Id` or `competition.CompetitionId`? Likewise with `CompetitionName`; it should just be `Name`. And, for what it's worth, you don't need `Required` for either a primary key or a non-nullable type (such as `int`). In either case, the property is required by default.

Comment: I think @ChW already gave the needed pointers, but thanks for adding to it.  What I'm still struggling to understand is how EF Core links entities.  What is happening is that in my example, competitions are being loaded and within the `CompetitionType` entity more competitions are being loaded incrementally. So the first competition has a `CompetitionTypes` entity with one competition.  The second has two competitions and so on.  What I want is something like a SQL join where in my `CompetitionTypes` entity I get all competitions that belong to that competition type.